# Return Redirect for Dynamic Routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel 6 and trying to figure out how to Return Redirect from one dynamic route to another.  I've tried many different things and get errors each time.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $data = request()->validate ([
        'type_of_preferred_network' => '',
        'cost_or_scale_more_important' => '',

    ]);

    $plansubmission = PlanSubmission::find($id);
    $plansubmission->update($data);

    return redirect ('broker/{'id'}/edit')->with(id, $id);
```

Comment: Welcome, can we see the route you have defined (in your question)? If you have a named route it's `return redirect()->route('NameOfYourRoute', ['id' => $id])`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Yes, the route is:

Comment: Route::resource ('networks', 'NetworksController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it solves your problem

```
 return redirect()->route('networks.edit',['id' => $id]);
```

Edit: Just try

```
 return redirect()->route('networks.edit',$id);
```

Or

```
 return redirect()->route('networks.edit',['network' => $id]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, still trying to figure it out.  I tried that and get:

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: networks.edit] [URI: networks/{network}/edit].

Comment: @Alexander try updated options in my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome.  The return redirect()->route('networks.edit',$id); did it.  Many thanks

Comment: @Alexander if this answer helped you `accept` and  `upvote` :)

Answer (score 0):

If your route (which is a different route than the one you posted in your question btw) is

```
Route::resource ('networks', 'NetworksController');
```

you can access/redirect to the edit action using

```
return redirect()->route('networks.edit', ['id' => $id]);
```

Laravel names resource actions accordingly: https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Edit: `'id'` is the name of the parameter used in the URL, if yours is (for whatever reason) `network` you should use

```
return redirect()->route('networks.edit', ['network' => $id]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that and getting back

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: networks.edit] [URI: networks/{network}/edit].